# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

Сan anybody help me with this error? It happens when I try to update post,
here's my update function

```
public function update(Requests\PostRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
        $data = $this->handleRequest($request);
        $post->update($data);
        return redirect('/blog/post')->with('message','Your posts was updated successfully');
    }
```

and here's my handleRequest function

```
private function handleRequest($request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $image = $request->file('image');
            $fileName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $destination = $this->uploadPath;

            $image->move($destination, $fileName);

            $data['image'] = $fileName;
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it’s this code throwing the error? Maybe the logic in the redirected page throws the error?  This code looks okay to me...

Comment: it redirect successfully when i remove $post->update($data);

Comment: why do you have this "Requests\PostRequest" instead of Request?

Comment: to validate input

Comment: You problem is with this line $post->update($data)

Answer (score 4):

You are accessing a `collection` instance, you need to access the underlying model:

```
foreach($post as $p){//loop through an Eloquent collection instance
    $p->fill($data);//mass assign the new values
    $p->save();//save the instance
}
```

Comment: Where the error is thrown, the exact line it is in, remove the update function call and replace it with this with correct variable names

Comment: it has another error, it says SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'testp' for key 'posts_slug_unique' (23000)

Comment: You have unique field in your database table and you are trying to update the field value with another that's already in there. I guess